# How to replace multiple async/await calls with Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, promise, async-await

I have the following `try/catch` block which is making 3 different api calls.
The following code is working fine but it is taking lot of time to execute when `firstData` has large dataset.

```
try {
    const firstData = await myservice1.myservice1Func();

    for(let i=0; i<firstData.total; i++){
        const hostName = firstData.rows[i]['hostname'];
        if (hostName !== null && firstData.rows[i]['myservice1Id'] !== null) {
            const aRes = await myService2(hostName);
            firstData.rows[i]['mylist'] =
                    aRes[0].dataValues;
        }
        if (hostName !== null && firstData.rows[i]['type'].includes('type1')) {
            const oRes = await myService3(hostName);
            firstData.rows[i]['ores'] = oRes.rows[0];
        }
        if (hostName !== null && firstData.rows[i]['type'].includes('type2')) {
            const vRes = await myService4(hostName);
            firstData.rows[i]['vRes'] = vRes.rows[0];
        }
    }
    return firstData;
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Here,

```
const firstData = 
{
  "total": 2,
  "rows": [
    {
      "hostname": "abc.com",
      "ipAddress": "11.11.11.11",
      "myservice1Id": "ee0f77c9-ef15",
      "type": "type1"
    },
    {
      "hostname": "cde.com",
      "ipAddress": "12.12.12.12",
      "type": "type2",
      "myservice1Id": null
    }
  ]
}   


const aRes = 
[
  {
        "listType": "list1",
        "createdAt": "2020-12-07"
  }
]


const oRes =
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "status": "FAIL"
    }
  ]
}


const vRes =
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "status": "FAIL"
    }
  ]
}
```

The final value of `firstData` returned is as following:

```
{
  "total": 2,
  "rows": [
    {
      "hostname": "abc.com",
      "ipAddress": "11.11.11.11",
      "myservice1Id": "ee0f77c9-ef15",
      "type": "type1",
      "oRes": {
        "status": "PASS"
      },
      "mylist": {
        "listType": "list1",
        "createdAt": "2020-12-07"
      }
    },
    {
      "hostname": "cde.com",
      "ipAddress": "12.12.12.12",
      "type": "type2",
      "myservice1Id": null,
      "vRes": {
        "status": "FAIL"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here, one thing to notice is that all the 3 `if blocks` can be executed in parallel because they are independent of each other.
Can I use `Promise.all` to execute all the 3 `if blocks` in `parallel`?
If yes, how the updated code will look like using `Promise.all`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest tweak would be to push each Promise to an array inside the `if`s:

```
const proms = [];
if (hostName !== null && firstData.rows[i].myservice1Id !== null) {
    proms.push(
      myService2(hostName)
        .then(aRes => firstData.rows[i].mylist = aRes[0].dataValues)
    );
}
// other ifs changed around the same way

await Promise.all(proms);
```

You could also make the code easier by making the `hostName` check only once, and it looks like you're iterating over the whole array, which can be done more easily by invoking the iterator:

```
try {
    const firstData = await myservice1.myservice1Func();
    for (const row of firstData.rows) {
        const hostName = row.hostname;
        if (hostName === null) continue;
        const proms = [];
        if (row.myservice1Id !== null) {
            proms.push(
                myService2(hostName)
                    .then(aRes => row.mylist = aRes[0].dataValues)
            );
        }
        // etc
```

Comment: can you please suggest where to include the `for loop`?

Comment: The same place it is in your current code. With the code in the answer, you'll be making up to 3 parallel requests, which is pretty reasonable, I wouldn't want to go much beyond that usually, though it depends on how much parallelism the service can handle.

Comment: In the end, should I do `return proms;`?

Comment: No, you just need `await Promise.all(proms);` as in the answer, and then after that point, that row will be fully populated

Comment: I am getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataValues' of undefined` Can you let me know where to add that check for undefined?

Comment: The Promise in the code in my answer is doing the same operation as in your original code - they're both `myService2(hostName)`. Your original code was referencing `aRes[0].dataValues` - if that works, `myService2(hostName).then(aRes => row.mylist = aRes[0].dataValues)` will work too. If it doesn't, and your original code works, it sounds like you mis-copied something.

Comment: If you need to tweak your original code and the new code to check that `aRes` has items, then just check if `aRes[0]` exists before trying to access its `dataValues` property

Comment: okay. can you let me know where to add the check to see if `aRes[0]` has items? will it be possible to update the answer?

Comment: Before the assignment to `row.mylist` - just use an `if` statement. This looks to be a completely separate issue to what you were asking about originally though

Comment: Eg `if(aRes[0])` checks to see if there's something in `aRes[0]`

Comment: okay. it is working now. one more thing, when I do `console.log(firstData)`, it is printing the original data in `firstData`.  It looks like `row.mylist = aRes[0].dataValues` is not updating the original `firstData`

Comment: Make sure you `await` the array of Promises, as in the answer: `await Promise.all(proms);` then log after that's done

Comment: when I add `        await Promise.all(proms);
        console.log(firstData);` then it goes to infinite loop after the `await Promise.all(proms);` statement

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that involves an infinite loop. Nothing is being repeated endlessly.

Comment: I am able to make it work after declaring `const proms = [];` outside the `for loop`

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have bit of code alterations,

```
for(let i=0; i<firstData.total; i++){
    const hostName = firstData.rows[i]['hostname'];

     //check if condition inside the service and return a null (a promise)
     Promise.all([myService2(hostName), myService3(hostName), myService4(hostName)]).then((values) => {
        console.log(values);
        //[resutl1,null,result3]
     });
}
```

Now the problem here is you have to wait until the slowest iteration to complete,
You can fix that with promise pool use,
[@supercharge/promise-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supercharge/promise-pool/)

[MDN Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) [Medium Blog Source](https://medium.com/@arsenyyankovsky/effective-limited-parallel-execution-in-javascript-ea2a1fb9a632)